# How to read zipped xml files using java

Tags: xml, file, zip

I am having a zip file with lot of xml files. I am having some data which I have to check with the xml files content and which ever xml file content matches with that data I have to extract that file only and store that in a folder.

Guide me to achieve this.

Thanking you.

--raaja.g

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. One thing you should know: We are not Rent-A-Coder. We will love to help you with specific problems and questions. But such a broad and unprecise question like this is unlikely to result in many helpful answers.
Try to rewrite the question. Tell us about what you have already tried. Show us your code (just the relevant parts). Then we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out javas [`ZipFile`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) and [`ZipEntry`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) classes.